# How to plot a scatter plot with its linear regression?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

How can I make an estimated line like that using matplotlib.

[image: Graph generated using excel]

I have several points and I plotted them using matplotlib using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for smp, lbl in zip(samples, labels):
    plt.scatter(smp[0], smp[1], marker='*', cl = 'b', s=100, label=lbl)

# set limit, xlabel, ylabel, legend ...
# ...

plt.show()
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should not plot every single point with it's own scatter command. It takes long and if you want to have a legend, you will have an entry for each point.
You could use this: `x = [value[0] for value in samples]` `y = [value[1] for value in samples]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `polyfit` to do linear regression:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import polyfit, poly1d

x, y = zip(*samples)

fit = polyfit(x, y, 1)
fit_fn = poly1d(fit)
plt.plot(x,y, '*', x, fit_fn(x), 'k')

plt.show()
```

**Example result:**

[image]

Comment: I think you just want `fit=polyfit(smp[0],smp[1],1)` as `smp[0]` is array like if its the first argument in `plt.scatter`. or just do `x=smp[0]; y=smp[1]`

Comment: @Gabriel No, according to the OP's `for` loop, the sample array would be of the format `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ..]`. So sorting `x` and `y` first (one way of another) seems necessary.

Comment: right, I see it now. was expecting multiple items in the legend of the OP plot if that was the case, but realize now that the OP code didn't make that image.